What is the purpose of select_id in Gizmo(bpy_struct)
I am trying to write a custom gizmo in which the movement of its 2 different elements will be responsible for two different properties of the object.
(I realize that the most correct way is to create two different Gizmo and call them in the same GizmoGroup).
But I'm not getting the hang of the select_id variable in the draw_select method.
I haven't found any information at all, neither how it works, nor what it's for. I even went to the old blender commit on github and it seems to be written that it doesn't work at all. And the comment was written either 2 or 5 years ago.
But my “experiments” show that it nevertheless somehow affects gizmo drawing (but all I achieved was laggy highlighting and wrong highlighting color (blue instead of orange)).
So the question is how this property works and how to work with it correctly.

I am not sure how crucial this custom Gizmo is but an alternative might be employing the new gizmo nodes inside the geometry nodes. However you do not have control over the color of the gizmos but you can attach geometry to gizmo which might work.
For instance Transform Gizmo:

This node would give you the following viewport elements:

There are other gizmo types like Dial Gizmo and Linear Gizmo
